# Current object property as value in same object different property

Tags: javascript, object, properties, dynamic

Sorry for such a random title, but have no idea how to explain it better. And therefore,  no idea if this is a duplicate question or not.

So, when declaring a new object, I'm looking to calculate the `giga` value:

```
var myObject = {
    super : 1,
    mega : 5,
    uber : 100,
    giga : this.super + this.mega + this.uber // super + mega + uber doesn't cut it either..
};
```

But this doesn't work, so, any ways of doing this while declaring, or not possible?

Hope I've made myself clear and thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Javascript 1.5 you can use the `get` keyword to define a getter

```
var obj = {
    super : 1,
    mega : 5,
    uber : 100,
    get giga() {
        return this.super + this.mega + this.uber;
    }
};

alert(obj.giga) // 106
```

more on this http://robertnyman.com/2009/05/28/getters-and-setters-with-javascript-code-samples-and-demos/

Comment: That will completely fall over on non-ES5 browsers. Please use `Object.defineProperty` to define getter/setters

Comment: There is no specification whether I'm interested in ES5 or ES4 or ESx, I see no reason for the downvote. In fact, this is the cleanest answer so far.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you have a really good reason for the need to do this inline, otherwise such
trickery is not really a good idea.

Here is what I came up with:

```
var myObject = (function(){
    this.giga = this.super + this.mega + this.uber;
    return this;
}).call({
    super : 1,
    mega : 5,
    uber : 100
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObject = {
    super : 1,
    mega : 5,
    uber : 100
};
myObject.giga = myObject.super + myObject.mega + myObject.uber;
```

Comment: There is a trailing comma, I had it as well when copypasting :P

Comment: @Esailija why I copy paste fail?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I meant I had the same error as you because I copypasted the OP's message, so I thought you had done so as well.