# Access object properties within object

Tags: javascript, object, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access JavaScript Object Literal value in same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659792/access-javascript-object-literal-value-in-same-object)

First look at the following JavaScript object

```
var settings = {
  user:"someuser",
  password:"password",
  country:"Country",
  birthplace:country
}
```

I want to set `birthplace` value same as `country`, so i put the object value `country` in-front of `birthplace` but it didn't work for me, I also used `this.country` but it still failed. My question is how to access the property of object within object.

Some users are addicted to ask "what you want to do or send your script etc" the answer for those people is simple "I want to access object property within object" and the script is mentioned above.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Regards

Comment: How's your country var defined?

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036740/current-object-property-as-value-in-same-object-different-property, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173610/can-a-javascript-object-property-refer-to-another-property-of-the-same-object

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can't reference an object during initialization when using *object literal* syntax. You need to reference the object after it is created.

```
settings.birthplace = settings.country;
```

---

Only way to reference an object during initialization is when you use a constructor function.

This example uses an anonymous function as a constructor. The new object is reference with `this`.

```
var settings = new function() {
    this.user = "someuser";
    this.password = "password";
    this.country = "Country";
    this.birthplace = this.country;
};
```

Comment: Starting with ECMAScript 2015 you can now use [Javascript getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and access the object within the object by doing:
```
const settings = { 
  country: "Country", 
  get birthplace() {
    return this.country,
  }
}
console.log(settings.birthplace); // outputs -> Country
```

Comment: to get the above code in es6, please check my answer below

Comment: @yukashimahuksay because the question has been closed a long time ago.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the object inside of itself. You can use variable:

```
var country = "country";
var settings = {
  user:"someuser",
  password:"password",
  country:country,
  birthplace:country
}
```