# How to access object data inside the object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have simple object as follows:

```
var obj={
 address:"http://localhost:8080",
 ajax:{
  login:address+"/login"
 }
}
```

I am getting error here `login:address+"/login"`

Can't I access address variable ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations) or [Access object properties within object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789141/access-object-properties-within-object) or many many others

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a value in an object that isn't defined yet. i.e. `obj.address` doesn't exist because you're not done defining it yet.

You'd need to define the variable outside the object first.

Comment: OP uses `address` not `obj.address`.

Comment: He does, but `address` doesn't refer to anything in the object `obj`. The link posted for how to do self-referential values provides a solution, I was just answering why he can't access it.