# Can't access values in JS object

Tags: javascript

I want to learn more OO JavaScript. I created something like that:

```
    var Player = {
        player: $('#player'),
        video: Player.player
    };

    console.log(Player.video);
```

`console.log` returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'player' of undefined`. Where's my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reference an object while initialization.
Explanation and suggested solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12789163/3992740) !

Show you may want something like this:

```
var Player = new function() {
    this.player = $('#player');
    this.video = this.player;
}; 

console.log(Player.player);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `Player` is not yet defined when assigning `video` property.

```
var Player = {
    player: $('#player'),
    video: Player.player  //<- Player is not defined yet. You are defining it right now.
};
```

Try setting `video` property after creating the object:

```
var Player = {
    player: $('#player')        
};
Player.video = Player.player;

console.log(Player.video);
```

Comment: I tried writing `Player = new Object()` at the beginning, but it doesn't help either.

Comment: Mhm. But! When I do this, and then define `Player.video = Player.player.get(0)` it returns error. Any idea why?

Comment: There may not be any HTML element with `id="player"`

Comment: There is one, a few lines before JS ;-)

Comment: Mmm... I think you should run your code from the handler of .ready() event. See http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: In your JS file, just define `var Player={};` (i.e it's a global variable). Then in the .ready() handler initialize your object: Player.player = $('#player'); Player.video = Player.player; console.log(Player.video);