# How to access other object sibling's value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm just wondering if it's possible to refer to self (object) value inside the object sibling like below?

```
[
  {
    "name": "Zulh",
    "name_uppercase": uppercase(self.name) // expects ZULH
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "name_uppercase": uppercase(self.name) // expects JOHN
  }
]
```

**Note**:

Code for `uppercase` is omitted for brevity. In my real code, it's doing synchronous complex stuff and is not actually simple string case manipulation like that.

Comment: No thats not possible.

Comment: @Red , are you sure about that ?

Comment: @MihaiT What Red meant was, it is not possible the way OP has written and `self.name` will not refer to current object. You will have to rely on loops or other functions/getter methods

Comment: @MihaiT What Rajesh said is exacly what I meant. The way OP wrote in his example is not possible.

Comment: How about using a getter?. Check my answer?

Answer (score 4):

### Using a GETTER

If you want to keep it dynamic and make it work even if you change the `name` property, you can use a [GETTER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) to do this kind of thing:

```js
const names = [
  {
    "name": "John",
    get name_uppercase() {
      return this.name.toUpperCase();
    }
  }
]

console.log(names[0].name_uppercase)
```

---

### GETTER for multiple objects

You don't have to write this for every property manually! Use [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const names = [
  {
    "name": "John"    
  },
  {
    "name": "Mike"
  }
]

names.forEach(object => {

  Object.defineProperty(object, 'nameUppercase', {
  
    get: function() { return this.name.toUpperCase() }
  
  });
  
});



console.log(names[0].nameUppercase)
console.log(names[1].nameUppercase)
```

---

### Using a class and a GETTER

Or as @Rajesh pointed out you can use a class instead:

```js
class Person {

  constructor(name) {
  
    this.name = name;
    
  }

  get nameUpperCase() {
  
    return this.name.toUpperCase();
  
  }

}

const names = [ new Person("John"), new Person("Mike")];

console.log(names[0].nameUpperCase);
console.log(names[1].nameUpperCase);
```

Comment: so OP has to write a `getter` for each and every object in the array?

Comment: A better approach would be to create a class and add this function to prototype

Comment: For more info on my previous comment, refer following **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a46v2wp9/4/)**

Comment: Indeed, that's what I thought about @Rajesh, I'll add this to my answer

Comment: @Ivan The point of defining a class is to eradicate unnecessary loop. Adding a getter property in loop is a bad idea. Hence I depicted both possible approaches in fiddle link

Answer (score 3):

[You can't reference an object during initialization when using object literal syntax.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789141/access-object-properties-within-object). Inshort, that's not possible what you expect above

Well, you can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and add additional/modified properties to you object like

```
data.map(o=> ({name: o.name, upper_case : o.name.toUpperCase()}))
```

```js
var data = [
  {
    "name": "Zulh" 
    
  },
  {
    "name": "John" 
   
  }
];

var x = data.map(o=> ({name: o.name, upper_case : o.name.toUpperCase()}))

console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and update the objects in Array

```js
var data = [{"name": "Zulh"},{"name": "John"}];
data.forEach(o=> o.upper_case = o.name.toUpperCase());
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a function that transforms your incoming array? A way to do it could be like this:

```js
const value = [
  {
    "name": "Zulh"
  },
  {
    "name": "John"
  }
];

const transform = ( array, propertyToUpdate, propertyToCreate, transformation ) => {
  return array.map( item => ({ ...item, [propertyToCreate]: transformation( item[propertyToUpdate] ) }) );
};

console.log( transform( value, 'name', 'name_uppercase', ( item ) => item.toUpperCase() ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with the object literal syntax, since it's 'this' property will not be set at that time. For example, if you'd run your code in the browser, 'this' would refer to the window object.

So you'll either have to use one of the other answers or go for a 'class':

```js
var uppercase = function( str ) {
  return str.toUpperCase();
};
var Person = function( name ) {
  this.name = name;
  this.name_uppercase = uppercase( this.name );
};
var persons = [
  new Person( 'zuhi' ),
  new Person( 'john' )
];
console.log( persons );
```

Same can be written in ES6 class syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 2 approaches:

1. If you DO NOT want to change your initial array ( which is recommended ), use `map` which returns a new array with changed values ( calls a function for every array item ) .

See below

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "name": "Zulh",
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
  }
];
const newArr = arr.map((x)=>{
 x.name_uppercase = (x.name).toUpperCase()
    return x
})
console.log(newArr)
```

2. If you don't mind changing your initial array, you can use `forEach`. Keep in mind that unlike `map`, `forEach` changes your array and so it doesn't return anything.

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "name": "Zulh",
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
  }
];
arr.forEach((x)=>{
  x.name_uppercase = (x.name).toUpperCase()
})
console.log(arr)
```

So it all depends if you want to change your current array or not

Answer (score 0):

How about using a getter method?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

> The get syntax binds an object property to a function that will be
>   called when that property is looked up.

```
foo = [
  {
    "name": "Zulh",
    get name_uppercase () {
        return (this.name).toUpperCase();
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    get name_uppercase () {
        return (this.name).toUpperCase();
    }
  }
]

console.log(foo[1].name_uppercase); //returns JOHN
```

Hope it helps :)