# Vue and simple store

Tags: vue.js

I created Vue application and I have simple store:

```
const paginationStore = {
  data: {
    entitiesDisplayOptions: [
      { value: '1', text: '1' },
      { value: '2', text: '2' },
      { value: '4', text: '4' },
      { value: '999999', text: 'All' },
    ],
    paginationLimits: {
      bottom: 0,
      top: paginationStore.data.entitiesDisplayOptions[0].value
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Why I can't set value from entitiesDisplayOptions to paginationStore.data.paginationLimits.top? What should I do to make it works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access object properties within object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789141/access-object-properties-within-object)

Comment: Why don't you use Vuex store?

Comment: Why do use Vuex store?

Comment: You can't do that. I mean during the initialization, so creation the object as object literal. You have to use another technique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store it in a variable outside the definition:

```
const newEntitiesDisplayOptions = [
      { value: '1', text: '1' },
      { value: '2', text: '2' },
      { value: '4', text: '4' },
      { value: '999999', text: 'All' },
];

const paginationStore = {
  data: {
    entitiesDisplayOptions: newEntitiesDisplayOptions ,
    paginationLimits: {
      bottom: 0,
      top: newEntitiesDisplayOptions[0].value
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is lot of possibilities. Everything you have to do is to remember you can't reference the other object properties at the moment of creation of object in the form of object literal.

```
const entitiesDisplayOptions = [
  { value: '1', text: '1' },
  { value: '2', text: '2' },
  { value: '4', text: '4' },
  { value: '999999', text: 'All' },
]

const paginationLimits = {
  bottom: 0,
  top: paginationStore.data.entitiesDisplayOptions[0].value
}

const paginationStore = {
  data: {
    entitiesDisplayOptions,
    paginationLimits
  }
}
```