# React state depends on other state

Tags: reactjs, state

I am relatively new to React and I have something that seems simple but is not working:

```
state = {
  apple: false,
  orange: false,

  appleOrOrange: (this.state.apple || this.state.orange)
}
```

I get an error saying this.state.apple is undefined. Anyone know how I could fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access object properties within object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789141/access-object-properties-within-object)

Comment: The thing is I want appleOrOrange to be updated when apple or orange is updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not create a state from another state. Compute the result always.

```js
class extends Component {
  state = {
    apple: false,
    orange: false,
  }

  render() {
    const appleOrOrange = this.state.apple || this.state.orange;
    ...
  }
}
```