# How to access the value inside array of object within that array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

**Update:**

Basically i want the same output but i restructured the content. I'm not sure if your answers are still up for that.

Please check my sandbox feel free to fork it here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/get-the-property-value-forked-hutww

So on `ContentData.js` i want my `image alt tag` to be dynamic and pull the content of it from key `name` it something like this `alt={this.name}` and it will generate to `alt="My alt tags"`

See the codes below:

**Content.js**

```html
import React, { Component } from "react";
import mainListsItems from "./ContentData";

class Content extends Component {
  render() {
    const myContent = mainListsItems.map((lists, k) => (
      <>
        <div key={k}>{lists.text}</div>
        {lists.mainContent.map((subcontent, j) => {
          return <div key={j}>{subcontent.contentAll}</div>;
        })}
      </>
    ));

    return <>{myContent}</>;
  }
}

export default Content;
```

**ContentData.js**

```html
import React from "react";

const listsData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "My alt tags",
    text: (
      <>
        <p>Lorem Imsum</p>
      </>
    ),
    mainContent: [
      {
        contentAll: (
          <>
            <p>
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
              industry.
            </p>
            <img
              alt=""
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1637704758245-ed126909d374?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxNHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
            />
          </>
        )
      }
    ]
  }
];

export default listsData;
```

Comment: Please add the error to the question.

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but have you considered setting the relevant `src` as the value itself? You could then replace the `<p>{x.content}</p>` with `<img src={x.content} alt={x.name} />`

Comment: I think you should take a look at [this answer to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12789163/9135987).

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to reference the same object during its initialization (using the `this` keyword), which is not allowed (on line 12). I would consider populating the `alt` in the same place where `name` is populated, reducing complexity on your frontend

Comment: It's better to put on the array only the src (so only the link instead of all the img tag) inside `content` and then take it from the `output` function where you can write the `<img .../>` tag

Comment: I just updated the comment and codes above, please check.

Answer (score 2):

`content` is defined inside the object while the object is being defined. So there is no `name` yet when `content` is being defined. Only after the assignment does `name` exist. You're referencing something that doesn't exist yet. So instead you can create a function that will be called at a later point after the object is defined and then the `name` can be referenced as shown below.

```
export default function App() {
const myData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Lorem Ipsum",
      content: function(){
        return (
        <>
          <img
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1637704758245-ed126909d374?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxNHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
            alt={this.name}
          />
        </>
      )
        }
    }
  ];

 const output = myData.map((x) => (
         <>
           <div key={x.id}>
             <p>{x.name} sa</p>
             <p>{x.content()}</p>
           </div>
         </>
  ));

  return <div className="App">{output}</div>;
}
```

Comment: I just updated the comment and codes above, please check.

Answer (score 1):

The `this`, in your case is referring the window object.

You can try to pass the name as a function value.
Something like this :

```js
const myData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Lorem Ipsum",
      content: (alt) => (
        <>
          <img
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1637704758245-ed126909d374?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxNHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
            alt={alt}
          />
        </>
      )
    }
  ];

const output = myData.map((x) => (
    <div key={x.id}>
      <p>{x.name} sa</p>
      <p>{x.content(x.name)}</p>
    </div>
  ));
```

Comment: I just updated the comment and codes above, please check.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the object in your myData array with a self executing function like this:

```js
 const myData = [
     function(){
        const entry = {
           id: 1,
           name: "Lorem Ipsum",
        }
        return {
          ...entry,
          content: (
             <>
               <img
                 src="your image source"
                 alt={entry.name}
               />
             </>
           )
        }
     }()
  ];
```

Comment: I just updated the comment and codes above, please check.